# How to create a page with two columns that can span pages to achieve my special goal?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, plain-tex

I am a Chinese plain TeX user and also a beginner. Now I encounter a hard question, that is

> I must write some numbered English paragraphs at the left column and its corresponding Chinese translations at the right column which have the same number with the English one. The first lines of the English paragraph and its corresponding Chinese translations should be located at the same horizontal line.

Here is an example if I can't explain this question clearly:
[image]

My method to solve this problem is using `\halign` with two `\vtop`, but it can't span pages or produce overfull, underfull `\vbox`.

```
\newcount\mycount
\mycount=1
\bigskip
\halign{\tabskip=.5in
        \vtop{\hsize=3in\noindent\number\mycount.\enspace#}&
        \tabskip=0pt\vtop{\hsize=3in
        \noindent\romannumeral\mycount.\enspace#\global\advance\mycount by1}\cr
        ...}
```

so ugly it is :-(

Anyone else has a better solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: yeah, I will follow you advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in `parallel` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{lipsum} %% dummy text
\usepackage{microtype} %% Just for my taste
\usepackage{enumitem}
%%%--------------- set a newlist for english--------------------
\newlist{eng}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[eng]{align=left,itemindent=2.5em,leftmargin=0pt,
rightmargin=.51\textwidth,label=\textbf{\arabic*.}}
%%%--------------- set a newlist for chinese --------------------
\newlist{chin}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[chin]{align=left,itemindent=2.5em,leftmargin=.51\textwidth,
rightmargin=0pt,label=\textbf{\roman*.}}
%%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}{.49\textwidth}{.49\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{%
\begin{eng}[series=english]
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{eng}
}%
\ParallelRText{%
\begin{chin}[series=chinese]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{chin}
}%
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{%
\begin{eng}[resume*=english]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{eng}
}%
\ParallelRText{%
\begin{chin}[resume*=chinese]
\item\lipsum[4]
\end{chin}
}%
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{%
\begin{eng}[resume*=english]
\item \lipsum[5]
\end{eng}
}%
\ParallelRText{%
\begin{chin}[resume*=chinese]
\item\lipsum[6]
\end{chin}
}%
\ParallelPar
\ParallelLText{%
\begin{eng}[resume*=english]
\item \lipsum[7]
\end{eng}
}%
\ParallelRText{%
\begin{chin}[resume*=chinese]
\item\lipsum[10]
\end{chin}
}%
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, but one inconvenient is that you have to hardcode the numbers...

Comment: @Jubobs: No more hard coding :-)

Comment: Please note the plain-tex -tag.

Comment: Harish, I have read the codes of this package today and gotten the main idea. Now I have realized a tiny edition for my purpose by using palin tex. You advice is very useful for me.

Comment: @morbusg Uh! Didn't see that. Any how I am not good in TeX. Keep it a secret ;-)